# Android: Re-invoke application if task manager kill

Tags: android, taskmanager

Application thread get close if its killed by task manager. Need to re-invoke application as though its killed by other application or task manager. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

You have to run background service with START_STICKY command.
Just extends Service and override onCommand like this :

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Like this your Service is restart when it's close (by system or anything else)

You just have now check on your service (onCreate for example) if application is running or not and launch it again if not. I suppose PackageManager let you check this or simply put a static boolean is_alive to see if your activity is always running.

Regards
Jim

Comment: Yup! called and used your snippet but when I manually force close my application and its does't re-invoked. yet same

Comment: Your service is running before you force close your application ? Put a Log in the onCreate method of your service like this you will see if it's launch and if it's launch again after close

Comment: Of course.. My service works until force close and service ideal after force close.. Also used your snippet accordingly in various manner. It makes my app not to ideal but when I force close.. doesn't works. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Normally if service is force close it have to be restart (cause of START_STICKY flag but maybe not directly after force close) In my application i also listen a lot of system event with a broadcast receiver on Manifest.xml and when an event occur i check if service is started and if not i launch it. It can be a solution for you to restart your activity.

Comment: can't believe this is up voted, I will kill your service & app in no time if you use just START_STICKY...I needed to work days to have an "unkillable" service

Answer (score 3):

[Bug in Android 2.3 with START_STICKY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619143/start-sticky-foreground-android-service-goes-away-without-notice/6877980#6877980)

I needed to keep alive a Service with all my forces. If the service is running anytime you can pop the UI.

```
onDestroy()
```

it will re-launch.

Can't be uninstalled the app, because it has a Device Administrator.

It is a kind of parental control, the user knows it is there.
Only way to stop is to remove the Device Admin, and uninstall it, but removing Device Admin will lock the phone as Kaspersky how it does.

There are a loot of braodcast receivers, such as boot finshed, user presen, screen on, screen off... , many other, all starting the service, you can do it with UI too. Or in the service check if your activity alive , visible, if not, than  pop it.

I hope you will use with good reason the info!

Edit: Restart service code snippet:

```
    // restart service:
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Intent myService = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    context.startService(myService);
```

Edit2: add spippet to check if the service is running in ... a load of Broadcasts

```
   public static  boolean isMyServiceRunning(Context context) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (MyService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                Log.d("myTag", "true");
                return true;
            }
        }
        Log.d("myTag", "false");
        return false;
    }
```

Edit3 other service start:

```
   public static void startTheService(Context context) {
         Intent myService = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
         context.startService(myService);
   }
```

Dont't forget Android 2.3 bug: do the logic for initialization in

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
```

and not in:

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
```

Comment: Thank you! but according to this [post](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle) its not guaranteed to onDestroy() because of stack flow in android system. And tried sample onDestroy to relaunch app. its yet same.

Comment: onDestroy it is 1 from many trying to restart none will guarantee, but in my case you can't kill for longer than 2 min the service

Comment: okay!and thank.. Can  you provide snippet of code or example to use onDestroy() method

Comment: yeah! already used such snippet to launch my service on startup of device and works. But it doesn't works on, when device is alive as I said. Thanks.. it could be helpful if I get onDestroy() method(snippet of code) to try in my code. Thank you!

Comment: there is, the first one, starting with //restart service

Answer (score 2):

While look at Google IO official product source code I have found the following

```
((AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE))
            .set(
                    AlarmManager.RTC,
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + jitterMillis,
                    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                            context,
                            0,
                            new Intent(context, TriggerSyncReceiver.class),
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
```

[URL for code](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/gcm/GCMIntentService.java)

You can start a sticky service and register an alarm manager that will check again and again that is your application is alive if not then it will run it.

You can also make a receiver and register it for `<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />` then you can start your service from your receiver. I think there should be some broadcast message when OS or kills some service/application.

Just to give you a rough idea I have done this and its working
1) register receiver 
Receiver Code:

@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

```
    try {
        this.mContext = context;
        startService(intent.getAction());

        uploadOnWifiConnected(intent);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.logException(ex);
        Console.showToastDelegate(mContext, R.string.msg_service_starup_failure, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}

private void startService(final String action) {
    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_BOOT)) {

        Util.startServiceSpawnProcessSingelton(mContext, mConnection);

    } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_SHUTDOWN)) {

    }
}
```

Service Code:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Logger.logInfo("Service Started onStartCommand");
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

I prefer doing nothing in onStartCommand because it will get called each time you start service but onCreate is only called 1st time service is started, so I do most of the code in onCreate, that way I don't really care about weather service is already running or not.

Comment: intent.getAction() returns null value and instead used ACTION_VIEW but yet same

Comment: +1, maybe it is not a perfect code, but the idea it is good, I have used the AlarmService, thanks to your idea. Not as is have you suggested, but I can figure out hot to meet perfectly my needs. I don't need the fish, just the fishing know how ;)

Answer (score 1):

according to @RetoMeyer from Google, the solution is to make the app "sticky".

for this, you must establisH START_STICKY in your intent service management.

check [this reference from developer android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: Its already been defined by gim(jaumard) and Algo but doesn't works

Comment: i have verious apps running that use this resource and they work perfectly well. Reto Meyer wrote the friggin book.  literally. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Once memory low issue comes android os starts killing application to compensate the required memory. Using services you can achieve this, your service should run parallely with your application but see, some of the cases even your service will be also killed at the same time. After killing if memory is sufficient android os itself try to restart the application not in all the cases. Finally there is no hard and fast rule to re-invoke your application once killed by os in all the cases it depends on os and internal behaviours.

Comment: yeah! but Ive seen some of application getting re-invoke. eg: [GO sms](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms&hl=en)
I wanna know, whether services to be added in code or permission yet to be given.

Comment: That's what I am saying use services .. refer these links : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339556/how-to-restart-android-application-from-within-application, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041971/android-service-killed, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257378/android-how-to-force-restart-service-os-killing-on-low-memory-behavior, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696861/how-can-we-prevent-service-from-killing-by-os-in-android.... better you try to workout, avoid restarting your application as your application is taking too much memory thats enough reason to be killed by os.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and link...am sorry.. My application is not killed by os for lack of memory.If user uses third party application to free memory every time, it gets killed.

Comment: like I told in my answer: make a Servive "unkillable". The Service will check if you activity is alive or not, if not than show it. Simpe to say, i wil not provide thousands of line of code...but here is the how to