# Disable or Remove Force Stop in manage applications

Tags: android, android-intent

Did quite some research but not able to get details on disabling FORCE STOP for the application.
While on GOOGLE play there are some applications like KASPERSKY PARENTAL CONTROL , Quick HEAL etc...who disable Force STOP.

Any clue about how to do this ?

Any help will be useful

Comment: your question is relevant to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400619/android-re-invoke-application-if-task-manager-kill) . Discussion in progress.. you may get some idea.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on ODM if they has some sort of business agreement they change in Android Setting app code and disable Force Stop button for those packages . Of course it has to pass CTS as well.Well i remember disabling Uninstall button for one app.

Answer (score -1):

If the processor gets eaten up, disabling "Force stop" will mean a user can only uninstall the app from Google Play or Device Settings (only if Device Admin is disabled)to free up running processes as well as potential memory leakage. Mobile security solutions by default will in general adhere to disabling "Force stop" for one good reason - malware could indeed "Force stop" the virus engine, rendering the Android device vulnerable to infection.

Also, if "Force stop" or "uninstall" is disabled the security app will ask for "Device admin" (used mainly in enterprise security) - a user can deactivate Device Administration by > Settings > Security > Device Administration - uncheck box. Once this is done, you can then "Force Stop" or "Uninstall" the app as normal from Settings or the Play Store. :)

Answer (score -1):

For s4 go to setting then slide right to 'more' and then hit 'Application manager' And then slide to see what apps are running or stopped.  Simple.. dont need to restore your phone guys. ..